# DCEF3 - guiClient - Access to MainForm resources from Extension class method

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

In example 'guiClient' of DCEF3 I try to modify TTestExtension.hello method by adding a reference to a resource in MainForm (changing text in editField of header...) :

```
class function TTestExtension.hello: string;
begin
  MainForm.edAddress.Text := 'Hello from Delphi'; 

  Result := 'Hello from Delphi';
end;
```

but it gives an exception of Access violation.
If in the previous code I put a reference to a file opened in MainForm, it gives a n exception of I/O (EInOutError).

Probably it's due to context / thread issue...

If I omit code lines to activate multi-process:

```
CefSingleProcess := false
```

application is working in single-process mode, the method is executed without errors; but I need multi-process...

What can I do to access MainForm resources from Extension's class functions in multi-process mode ?

Comment: Which thread does this method execute in? The main GUI thread? What value has `MainForm`? Is it assigned? Are you aware of the VCL threading rules? Specifically VCL code must execute in the main thread. A rule which I suspect you are breaking.

Comment: It is executed in thread of Extension, so, I think ,in TChromium browser's thread. To execute it in main thread how can I get it ?

Comment: Call `TThread.Synchronize`

Comment: I create a procedure in MainForm to do operations: 

procedure TMainForm.myFunc();
begin
  MainForm.edAddress.Text := 'test';
end;

and I call from TExtension.hello with:

Synchronize(MainForm.myFunc);

but compiler gives error:

[DCC Error] main.pas(531): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to debug that error. I'm not going to attempt to guess given the sparse amount of code, and its lack of formatting